# Связь many-to-many и условие IN

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть 3 таблицы: `orders`, `managers`, `order_managers` (таблица для привязки N менеджеров к заказу)

Выборка происходит так:

```
SELECT 
  *, group_contact(order_managers.manager_id) as menagers_ids 
FROM orders INNER JOIN order_managers ON order_managers.order_id=orders.id
GROUP BY orders.id
```

Но потребовалось сделать выборку по конкретному manager_id. И если я добавляю в условие WHERE, или JOIN manager_id=?i, то это конечно сработает, но в результате выборки в menagers_ids поместится только 1 менеджер, тот, по которому был поиск и это не удивительно.

Раньше я бы делал вообще 2 запроса, второй для того, чтобы достать идентифкаторы менеджеров, сейчас я узнал про интересное решение с group_contact. Но что то для условия в подобных решений не удалось найти. У самого приходит на ум конечно сделать через HAVING, но не понимаю как делать проверку IN с полем group_contact. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, я не очень понял вопрос

Comment: Как получить заказы, в которых учавствует менеджер с идентификатором 81 например. При этом, чтобы в managers_ids упали все менеджеры по данным заказам(в которых участвовал 81 менеджер), а не только 81.

Comment: `SELECT 
      *, group_contact(om.manager_id) as menagers_ids 
    FROM orders o INNER JOIN order_managers ON om.order_id=o.id
    WHERE o.order_id IN
      (SELECT
          t.order_id
       FROM order_managers t
       WHERE t.manager_id = 81)
    GROUP BY orders.id`

Comment: Я бы так ответил, но не уверен, что вы это спрашиваете

Comment: Да, это сработало! Спасибо! Но думал что такое можно реализовать как нибудь без подзапроса. Но видимо только такое решение, тоже приятное! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи обычного SQL

```
SELECT 
  *, group_contact(om.manager_id) as menagers_ids 
FROM orders o INNER JOIN order_managers ON om.order_id=o.id
WHERE o.order_id IN
  (SELECT
      t.order_id
   FROM order_managers t
   WHERE t.manager_id = 81)
GROUP BY orders.id
```

Функция group_contact возвращает строку, оператор `IN` соответственно со строками не работает. Можно каждый идентификатор обрамлять каким-нибудь символом, чтобы строка получилась вида `#1111#2222#81#` и искать как подстроку `#81#`, но такое решение специфичное.